# Pandas: Why are the values returned in one instance and just the df name in another? In the latter case I have the run another line of code

Tags: python, pandas

If I input values into the function below, I get output values:

```
#Correlation vector
#Excluding the target variable itself, find the top n features- ranked by absolute value desc 
def correlation_vector(d, v, n):
    corrresult = d.drop(v, axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.corr(d[v])) # <- d[v] 

    return corrresult
```

However, when I add 'dropna(inplace=True)' to the function (4th line), the output is the name of the resulting df? I have to run the df itself after to get the values:

```
#Correlation vector
#Excluding the target variable itself, find the top n features- ranked by absolute value desc 
def correlation_vector(d, v, n):
    corrresult = d.drop(v, axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.corr(d[v])).dropna(inplace=True) 
    return corrresult
```

Comment: `dropna(inplace=True)` returns a `None` value. remove `inplace=True` then you would get a dataframe.

Comment: I tried that. No error but there's still NaNs in the data. The df is unchanged from before- apart from '<bound method Series.dropna of' being added to the top.

Comment: It sounds like you removed the parentheses as well as the `inplace=True`. Don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about if you modify your function in something like this?

```
#Correlation vector
def correlation_vector(d, v, n):
    corrresult = d.drop(v, axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.corr(d[v]))
    corrresult.dropna(inplace=True)
 
    return corrresult
```